# Detecting an existing account: coinbase or getAccounts?

Tags: metamask, accounts

When detecting web3 or even an existing node, one typically needs to detect an account - which also gives an indication if the account needs to be unlocked.

Should the check for an account be a lookup for accounts[0] from getAccounts or the coinbase property?

I believe the ordering of accounts is based on the name and that it is possible that coinbase != accounts[0] if running a private node?

So which would be better, particularly for MetaMask?
Does it matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe the ordering of accounts is based on the name and that it is possible that coinbase != accounts[0] if running a private node?

No ordering of accounts depends on the time of creation. First account created is accoount[0] and then the sequence goes on.

Coinbase is the accounts that get the minor reward. If a coinbase account is not defined explicitly, first account created i.e accounts[0] is the coinbase account.

Comment: thanks, I see now in the wiki(https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts):

"The newest format of the keyfiles is: UTC--<created_at UTC ISO8601>-<address hex>. The order of accounts when listing, is lexicographic, but as a consequence of the timespamp format, it is actually order of creation"